# Background music game play goes right but stop gives an exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

I'm trying to play some music for my game in the background. The music will never stop unless the user turns it off in settings. The music will always play in the background for each view and doesn't pause or something.

For this reason I've made a singleton class for my background music. But when I press "Stop the music", the app breakpoints for an exception (I'm not seeing one, so I don't know what's wrong).

The music still stops, but there is something wrong and I don't know what. Is it right to make it in a singleton class, or do I need to solve this on an other way?

**Here is a screenshot of when the exception happens:**
[image: Image about the exception]

**Here is the code for my singleton class:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface Music : NSObject

@property AVAudioPlayer *player;

- (void)stop;
- (void)play;

+ (Music *)sharedInstance;

@end

#import "Music.h"

@implementation Music

+ (Music *)sharedInstance {

    static Music *sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{

        sharedInstance = [[Music alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                             pathForResource:@"water_2"
                                             ofType:@"wav"]];

        self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
        self.player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)stop{
    [self.player stop];
}

- (void)play{
    [self.player play];
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what the exception is, it's going to be very hard to help. Is there a reason you can't see the exception but you know one is happening?

Comment: I have a general breakpoint for all exceptions. So when I press stop music, the app pauses, like a normal exception but without more information, i can just resume the app if i want to, but this doesn't seems right to me the app pauses always there. I'll edit my OP with a screenshot of the "exception"

Comment: Try making your breakpoint break only on Objective C exceptions and see if you still are halting at the breakpoint. In the past I've had issues with unhandled C++ exceptions being thrown inside iOS audio frameworks (through no fault of my own code).

Answer (score 0):

I would switch up your code and I would use an IBAction instead of void stop and void play

```
-(IBAction)stop {

[player stop];

}

-(IBAction)play {

[player play];

}
```

Comment: Why? All that does is allow the OP to hook up the start/stop methods to controls in interface builder. It should have no effect on the issue at hand (NOTE: you may be right and there's some bizarre bug that is fixed by using IBAction but it bears some explanation)

Comment: I have no intention of hooking an UIButton or some to my stop/play. These are called by my gesturerecoginzers.